# Java OutOfMemoryError / OrientDB WAL Flush Task error after importing 2M records into OrientDB

Tags: java, database, out-of-memory, orientdb, wal

After one of my import scripts had completed importing all data, I tried restarting it to grab any updated data. The first thing it does is grab the most recently updated record:

```
db.select().from(newClass).order('updatedAt desc').limit(1).one()
```

However, that caused the following error from my Node script:

```
Possibly unhandled OrientDB.RequestError: Java heap space
    at Operation.parseError (/Users/gsquare567/node_modules/oriento/lib/transport/binary/protocol/operation.js:779:13)
    at Operation.consume (/Users/gsquare567/node_modules/oriento/lib/transport/binary/protocol/operation.js:369:35)
    at Connection.process (/Users/gsquare567/node_modules/oriento/lib/transport/binary/connection.js:324:17)
    at Connection.handleSocketData (/Users/gsquare567/node_modules/oriento/lib/transport/binary/connection.js:250:17)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (_stream_readable.js:748:14)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:92:17)
    at emitReadable_ (_stream_readable.js:410:10)
    at emitReadable (_stream_readable.js:406:5)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:168:9)
```

And I received the following server output:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
Dumping heap to java_pid1694.hprof ...
Heap dump file created [2055557443 bytes in 37.799 secs]
Error on fetching record during browsing. The record has been skipped
Error on retrieving record #11:1023466 (cluster: user)
-> com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.raw.ODatabaseRaw.read(ODatabaseRaw.java:252)
-> com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.record.ODatabaseRecordAbstract.executeReadRecord(ODatabaseRecordAbstract.java:1017)
-> com.orientechnologies.orient.core.tx.OTransactionNoTx.loadRecord(OTransactionNoTx.java:65)
-> com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.record.ODatabaseRecordTx.load(ODatabaseRecordTx.java:264)
-> com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.record.ODatabaseRecordTx.load(ODatabaseRecordTx.java:40)
-> com.orientechnologies.orient.core.iterator.OIdentifiableIterator.readCurrentRecord(OIdentifiableIterator.java:285)
-> com.orientechnologies.orient.core.iterator.ORecordIteratorClusters.hasNext(ORecordIteratorClusters.java:139)
-> com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.OCommandExecutorSQLSelect.fetchFromTarget(OCommandExecutorSQLSelect.java:913)
-> com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.OCommandExecutorSQLSelect.executeSearch(OCommandExecutorSQLSelect.java:397)
-> com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.OCommandExecutorSQLSelect.execute(OCommandExecutorSQLSelect.java:358)
-> com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.OCommandExecutorSQLDelegate.execute(OCommandExecutorSQLDelegate.java:60)
-> com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.OStorageEmbedded.executeCommand(OStorageEmbedded.java:94)
-> com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.OStorageEmbedded.command(OStorageEmbedded.java:83)
-> com.orientechnologies.orient.core.command.OCommandRequestTextAbstract.execute(OCommandRequestTextAbstract.java:59)
-> com.orientechnologies.orient.server.network.protocol.binary.ONetworkProtocolBinary.command(ONetworkProtocolBinary.java:1181)
-> com.orientechnologies.orient.server.network.protocol.binary.ONetworkProtocolBinary.executeRequest(ONetworkProtocolBinary.java:340)
-> com.orientechnologies.orient.server.network.protocol.binary.OBinaryNetworkProtocolAbstract.execute(OBinaryNetworkProtocolAbstract.java:169)
-> com.orientechnologies.common.thread.OSoftThread.run(OSoftThread.java:45)
GC overhead limit exceeded
```

My other import script, running concurrently, also stopped due to the following:

```
"error":{"name":"OrientDB.RequestError","message":"Java heap space","data":{},"previous":[],"id":1,"type":"java.lang.OutOfMemoryError","hasMore":0}
```

After trying to run the original script again, I got the following output in my server:

```
Exception in thread "OrientDB WAL Flush Task (pumpup)" Error on client connection
Java heap spacejava.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

Node script output:

```
Possibly unhandled OrientDB.RequestError: Java heap space
    at Operation.parseError (/Users/gsquare567/node_modules/oriento/lib/transport/binary/protocol/operation.js:779:13)
    at Operation.consume (/Users/gsquare567/node_modules/oriento/lib/transport/binary/protocol/operation.js:369:35)
    at Connection.process (/Users/gsquare567/node_modules/oriento/lib/transport/binary/connection.js:324:17)
    at Connection.handleSocketData (/Users/gsquare567/node_modules/oriento/lib/transport/binary/connection.js:250:17)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (_stream_readable.js:748:14)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:92:17)
    at emitReadable_ (_stream_readable.js:410:10)
    at emitReadable (_stream_readable.js:406:5)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:168:9)
```

**EDIT**

After increasing the memory limit to 2GB, I was able to insert 5M records (instead of the previous 2M records) but am still hitting this error.

```
GC overhead limit exceeded
-> com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.raw.ODatabaseRaw.read(ODatabaseRaw.java:252)
-> com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.record.ODatabaseRecordAbstract.executeReadRecord(ODatabaseRecordAbstract.java:1017)
-> com.orientechnologies.orient.core.tx.OTransactionNoTx.loadRecord(OTransactionNoTx.java:65)
-> com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.record.ODatabaseRecordTx.load(ODatabaseRecordTx.java:264)
-> com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.record.ODatabaseRecordTx.load(ODatabaseRecordTx.java:40)
-> com.orientechnologies.orient.core.iterator.OIdentifiableIterator.readCurrentRecord(OIdentifiableIterator.java:285)
-> com.orientechnologies.orient.core.iterator.ORecordIteratorClusters.hasNext(ORecordIteratorClusters.java:139)
-> com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.OCommandExecutorSQLSelect.fetchFromTarget(OCommandExecutorSQLSelect.java:913)
-> com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.OCommandExecutorSQLSelect.executeSearch(OCommandExecutorSQLSelect.java:397)
-> com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.OCommandExecutorSQLSelect.execute(OCommandExecutorSQLSelect.java:358)
-> com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.OCommandExecutorSQLDelegate.execute(OCommandExecutorSQLDelegate.java:60)
-> com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.OStorageEmbedded.executeCommand(OStorageEmbedded.java:94)
-> com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.OStorageEmbedded.command(OStorageEmbedded.java:83)
-> com.orientechnologies.orient.core.command.OCommandRequestTextAbstract.execute(OCommandRequestTextAbstract.java:59)
-> com.orientechnologies.orient.server.network.protocol.binary.ONetworkProtocolBinary.command(ONetworkProtocolBinary.java:1181)
-> com.orientechnologies.orient.server.network.protocol.binary.ONetworkProtocolBinary.executeRequest(ONetworkProtocolBinary.java:340)
-> com.orientechnologies.orient.server.network.protocol.binary.OBinaryNetworkProtocolAbstract.execute(OBinaryNetworkProtocolAbstract.java:169)
-> com.orientechnologies.common.thread.OSoftThread.run(OSoftThread.java:45)
Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "Timer-0"
```

Comment: Generally there are 2 options to resolve OOME: Increse available memory or reduce the consumption

Comment: How much memory do you have? You can change it in bin/server.sh file by adding -Xmx2G to last line (where Java is launched) assigning 2G (max) to OrientDB.

Comment: I Luca, I've done that and this time I made it to 5M rows, but it's still not enough. I can't run any queries on my data now and will likely have to recreate my database because this causes the WAL error. How is it possible to have billions of records?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that you are trying to sort all 5M records.

That operation have to load whole dataset in memory to sort it (We actually have a plan to optimize it to avoid OOM in this cases, but it is not implemented yet).

So even if you specify limit 1 you load whole bunch of records and query will be slow and consume a lot of memory.

To optimize that query **build an index** over *updatedAt* field.

Comment: Would you recommend a `NOTUNIQUE_HASH_INDEX` if these are `DATETIME` that are not unique?

Comment: It worked with `NOTUNIQUE` and not with `NOTUNIQUE_HASH_INDEX`. After looking at the docs, the latter does not support range queries, so this makes sense.